# Routes When Importing Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am currently attempting to add routing to my Angular 2 project. All of the components work, but when I add 'appRoutes' to my imports on app.module.ts , an error gets thrown saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { appRoutes } from './app.router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { WorkComponent } from './work/work.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';



@NgModule({     
declarations: [
AppComponent,
NavigationComponent,
AboutComponent,
ResumeComponent,
WorkComponent,
BlogComponent,
HomeComponent
],
imports: [
appRoutes,
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent, NavigationComponent, AboutComponent,
            ResumeComponent, WorkComponent, BlogComponent, HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.router.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { WorkComponent } from './work/work.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes =[
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent },
  { path: 'work', component: WorkComponent },
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Any help would be appreciated. The page works until I add the `appRoutes` import, then it just sits on Loading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my own problem. I deleted every component from bootstrap: [...] besides the AppComponent, but kept the other components in the declarations and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need ModuleWithProviders. Remove that from:

```
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

i.e.

```
export const routes: RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and see if it works. (Also clean up by removing the import).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried your solution and nothing happened. I also tried replacing the ':' after routes with an '=' but still nothing. I've seen demos do it the way I have it and it works that's why I'm so confused.